# 1D multipole Green's functions for the wave equation

Tags: waves, acoustics, greens-functions

What are the Green's functions for longitudinal multipole sources for the homogeneous scalar wave equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The monopole solution**

Consider the 1-D wave equation for the Green's function solution $G$:
$$\left[\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{ \partial^2  }{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \right]G(x,t|\xi) = \delta(x-\xi)\delta(t).$$
In the frequency domain this gives:
$$\left[\frac{\omega^2}{c^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \right]\hat{G}(x,\omega|\xi) = -\delta(x-\xi).$$
The solution to this problem is well-known:
$$\hat{G}(x,\omega|\xi) = -\frac{i}{2}\frac{c}{\omega} e^{-i\frac{\omega}{c} \lvert x - \xi \rvert}. $$

**The dipole solution**

Then, for the multipole we place two lower-order poles next to each other with opposite polarity. In particular, for the dipole we assume the space-time source-function is given as $\tfrac{\partial \delta(x-\xi)}{\partial x}\delta(t)$, i.e., the spatial derivative of the delta function. We find the dipole solution by a integration of the Green's function with this new source function. Extending it for the $n$-pole ($n=0$ for monopole, $n=1$ for the dipole, ...) solution:
$$ \hat{G}_\text{$n$-pole}(x,\omega|\xi) = \int \hat{G}(x,\omega|x')\frac{\partial^n \delta(x'-\xi)}{\partial x'^n} \text{d}\! x' = (-1)^n\frac{\partial^n \hat{G}(x,\omega|\xi)}{\partial \xi^n}. $$
Carrying this out, I find for the dipole (note: $\partial \lvert x-\xi \rvert/\partial \xi = -\text{sign}(x-\xi)$):
\begin{align} \hat{G}_\text{dipole}(x,\omega|\xi) & = (-1) \left( -i\frac{\omega}{c} \right)\left( -\text{sign}(x-\xi) \right) \left( -\frac{i}{2}\frac{c}{\omega} e^{-i\frac{\omega}{c} \lvert x - \xi \rvert} \right),\\
& = -\frac{1}{2}\text{sign}(x-\xi) e^{-i\frac{\omega}{c} \lvert x - \xi \rvert} \end{align}
I could confirm this solution is correct in a finite-difference simulation: at $x=\xi$ the solution is indeed 0, as predicted by the sign function.

**The quadrupole solution**

I can continue in a straightforward fashion. With the formula for the $n$-th pole from above, for $n=2$ I find (note: $\partial \text{sign}(x-\xi)/\partial \xi = -2\delta(x-\xi)$):
\begin{align} \hat{G}_\text{quadrupole}(x,\omega|\xi) & = \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\left( \frac{1}{2}\text{sign}(x-\xi) e^{-i\frac{\omega}{c} \lvert x - \xi \rvert} \right),\\
& = \frac{i}{2}\frac{\omega}{c}\text{sign}^2(x-\xi) e^{-i\frac{\omega}{c} \lvert x - \xi \rvert} - \delta(x-\xi)e^{-i\frac{\omega}{c} \lvert x - \xi \rvert} \\
& = \frac{i}{2}\frac{\omega}{c}\text{sign}^2(x-\xi) e^{-i\frac{\omega}{c} \lvert x - \xi \rvert} - \delta(x-\xi) \end{align}
We can think of $\text{sign}^2(x)$ as the opposite of a $\delta$ function: it is 1 for all $x\neq \xi$. Conversely, the second term describes exactly what happens at $x=\xi$, for which the exponential is simply equal to 1. I could confirm this also in a finite-difference simulation.

**The octopole solution**
This is where I get into trouble; because I have 2 derivatives that I cannot formulate!
\begin{align} \hat{G}_\text{octopole}(x,\omega|\xi) & = (-1)\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\left( \frac{i}{2}\frac{\omega}{c}\text{sign}^2(x-\xi) e^{-i\frac{\omega}{c} \lvert x - \xi \rvert} - \delta(x-\xi) \right). \end{align}
The derivative of $\text{sign}^2(x)$ is not straightforward. From the chain rule I would guess it's 0 $2\text{sign}(x)\delta(x)=0$? That suggests:
\begin{align} \hat{G}_\text{octopole}(x,\omega|\xi) & =  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\text{sign}^3(x-\xi) e^{-i\frac{\omega}{c} \lvert x - \xi \rvert} + \frac{\partial \delta(x-\xi)}{\partial \xi}. 
\end{align}
This appeared to work correctly in the FD simulation; though it's of course not trivial to model octopoles...

NB. The space-time domain versions of these produce for some wavelet $s(t)$:
\begin{align}
    \textbf{Monopole:}\  {G}(x,t|\xi) & = \frac{v_p}{2} s^\text{integrated}\left( t - \frac{\lvert{x-\xi}\rvert}{v_p}\right) , \\
    \textbf{Dipole:}\  {G}(x,t|\xi) & = -\frac{1}{2}\text{sign}(x-\xi) s\left( t - \frac{\lvert{x-\xi}\rvert}{v_p}\right), \\
    \textbf{Quadrupole:}\  {G}(x,t|\xi)  & = \frac{1}{2v_p}\text{sign}^2(x-\xi) s^\text{differentiated}\left( t -  \frac{\lvert{x-\xi}\rvert}{v_p}\right)  - \delta(x-\xi)s(t),
    \\
    \textbf{Octopole:}\  {G}(x,t|\xi)  & = - \frac{1}{2v_p^2}\text{sign}(x-\xi)s^\text{twice differentiated}\left( t -  \frac{\lvert{x-\xi}\rvert}{v_p}\right) + \frac{\partial \delta(x-\xi)}{\partial x}s(t).
\end{align}